# Promise polyfill does not work in FireFox and IE11 when added via Webpack babel-loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, apollo-client, polyfills, babel-loader

I got hit with below peculiar issue on promise polyfill that should be added by Babel's preset-env for browser compatibility.

I have a `Foo.ts` file which uses the `async/await` syntax to handle promises. After being processed by `babel-loader`, bundled and started by Webpack dev server, the containing React web application runs successfully in Chrome, Safari, Edge(Mac) but fails in FireFox, IE11 and Edge(Windows).

The error looks like below, which is identified to be from the npm package `@apollo/client` which `Foo.ts` depends on. Does it indicate that the promise polyfill is missing?

```
TypeError: "this.fetchQuery(...).finally is not a function"
```

The Webpack config for babel-loader looks like below.

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules\/.*/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-react',
            '@babel/preset-typescript',
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: '3.6',
                debug: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
          plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
        },
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

When the dev server starts, in the console output I am able to see below line that says the promise polyfill has been added to `Foo.js`.

```
Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.promise { "chrome":"45", "edge":"12", "firefox":"45", "ie":"11", "safari":"10.1" }
```

Hence I am confused how the problem could have occurred.

If I manually add `import 'core-js/es/promise/finally';` to `Foo.ts`, everything just works.

I am wondering what could be missing here and why that polyfill is not successfully added by `babel-loader`.

The code portion in `Foo.ts` that involves `@apollo/client` looks like below. It's compiled to `ES2015` target by `tsc` before going through babel transformation.

```js
try {
  const response: ApolloQueryResult<QueryType> = await this.apolloClient.query(
    {
      query,
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
      variables,
    },
  );
  return response.data;
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  throw e;
}
```

**Env Info**

- Firefox: 68.8.0esr
- @babel/preset-env: 7.9.5
- core-js: 3.6.5
- Webpack: 4.29.6
- babel-loader: 8.0.5

Answer (score 1):

After further digging, I think the problem is caused by `@babel/preset-env` not able to inject the correct `es.promise` polyfill for Firefox. I tested with below config which isolates the target running environment to Firefox only. The issue is only observed for Firefox version set at 68 and lower.

```
      targets: {
        firefox: '68',
      },
```

For now my workaround is:

1. Config `@babel/preset-env` to purposely exclude `es.promise` polyfill.

```
exclude: ['es.promise'],
```

2. Add it through Webpack's entrypoint config since it's still needed.

```
entry: ['core-js/es/promise', 'index.ts'],
```

Comment: I posted an issue report to seek more advice. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12029